# Table in a div overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

I have a table in a div and set my `overflow:auto` in this container div.
I get a horizontal scroll bar, but not a vertical one when there are many rows. 
Whats the problem?

Comment: I've given a few ideas below but posting the html (or reasonable fragment) might also be useful. Both scroll bars come up for me with auto when I try.

Comment: @CrabBucket - You know, It's really refreshing to see someone ask for clarification on a question without being a jerk about it. It's a tiny thing, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try `overflow:scroll` instead. Will force the scroll bars to appear - [full description](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html) .

Alternatively it could be because you haven't set a height to the div (more likely). Try setting one and see if that improves things.

Alternatively has the container div got the height set too big so preventing the vertical scroll.

To be honest I'm trying it and I'm finding it hard to stop the horizontal scroll from appearing (as long it is `scroll:auto`)

Maybe I've missed (misunderstood) something.